# Azure Active Directory Premium MFA Attributes via Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory

How to programatically control the attributes that are attached to an AAD Premium user, related to MFA? Using the Graph API (C#, using the SDK), what calls can be made to make a user MFA or not, CRUD on phone numbers, etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such API we can get the MFA attributes through Graph REST API, since there is no relative attribute in [user entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity).

However, we can using the Azure Multi-Factor Authentication SDK to build multi-factor authentication into custom Apps. More detail about this, you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/multi-factor-authentication/multi-factor-authentication-sdk).

Answer (score 0):

These attributes are now available in the Microsoft Graph Beta API. See the documentation at [Azure AD authentication methods API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/authenticationmethods-overview?view=graph-rest-beta).