# Azure Active directory MFA for REST API

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I've a custom application registered with Azure AD.
Recently I've enabled MFA using Conditional Access Policies.
MFA works based on the policies but it won't work when application accessed via the **REST API**.

How to enforce MFA when users are making **/rest** API calls to the application which is backed by MFA?

Can we utilize something like Expose API?

Comment: Are you looking for some way to avoid users getting blocked by MFA while calling REST APIs using access tokens?

Comment: No, it is the other way around.
So any user calls the REST API should be asked by MFA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft won’t support MFA for Rest API and there is no API for MFA attributes through Rest API.

For more details you can go through the below links
[MFA for Rest API]
(https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/26aeec21-158a-45f0-84bb-5c952da73aeb/mfa-rest-apis)
[MFA Attributes]
([Azure Active Directory Premium MFA Attributes via Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156206/azure-active-directory-premium-mfa-attributes-via-graph-api))

Also You can have a third party application for MFA Rest API
Below is the link
[REST API MFA]
(https://docs.acceptto.com/docs/api/api)